# Twilio long code numbers is getting blocked because of carrier filtering

Tags: node.js, twilio

We are facing issue with Twilio on delivering messages.

We have tried to send messages using the shortcode and long code:

With shortcode, we got the large throughput of sending messages but the problem is if we have US shortcode and want to send the message to Canada it will not work.
Another issue is if DND is activated on users phone number then shortcode will not reach to that user's phone.

So DND is one of the main problems and because of this, we switched to another approach of cycling long code numbers to send the message.

But by acquiring this approach, we got the same issue of content violation by the carrier with error code 30007, which states that:
If a message you sent is not delivered to the end device and returns a 30007 error code, this means that your message was filtered out due to a carrier violation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question for Stack Overflow. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who may be able to work with you to help you avoid carrier violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue we come up with a solution of sending messages via Copilot and add more numbers to Twilio Messaging Service. This will distribute the load across multiple numbers.

Please find the link to know more about Copilot and Messaging Services:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services

Please enlighten us with the approach we are going to take.